# Repeatedly asking to trust the developer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an ios app that uses Google Places. The problem I am facing while testing the app is that the app repeatedly asks to verify the developer on ios device and on the other hand the ios device shows that app is verified. 
Please help me with this issue and apologies for such a beginner level question.

Comment: Verify the developer? Are you building an enterprise app?

Comment: yes, it's an enterprise app and I am a beginner to ios development

Comment: it is how it is – why is it a problem to mark the certificate trusted? that is for your and your client's interest after all.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell your device to permanently trust this developer in the settings menu, I think it may be in `General -> Profiles` or `General -> Profile Management`. Once there and when you have an enterprise app installed you should have an additional option for 'Developer Trust Settings'. Select your developer in there and trust it.

Comment: i followed these steps about 10 times every time i have to trust the developer but the ios device actually shows that the app is verified still xcode asks to trust the developer.

Comment: Is this after removing the app from the device and re-installing?

Comment: Once you remove the app, the permission settings are lost. This is what is causing your issue. Just install the updated version over the new one